# Kernel mode Free BSD socket

Tags: sockets, kernel, mode, bsd

In FreeBSD, I am attempting to create a 2way communication between a loadable kernel module(driver) and a user mode app/daemon. I am attempting with a socket !. In Linux there is Netlink socket library. But FreeBSD do not have one such exclusive IPC mechanism for kernel<---->User communication. Is there any open source code available. Thanks.

Comment: The same is done in Linux using NETLINK. But how to do it in FreeBSD ?

Comment: If there was it would have to have a kernel component. Does that fit your constraints?